# Limit number of visible context menu items in Android

Tags: android, android-menu

The number of option menu items can change on runtime in my app, depending on the actions of the user.

I am using this right now for my menu items :

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

If there is enough room in some cases there are 4 menu items visible in the actionbar. Is there a way to limit the visible menu items?

In my case, I want maximum 2 menu items visible in the actionbar, the additional entries should be in the "more" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force maximum two visible `MenuItem` as action buttons on the actionbar by setting:

```
app:showAsAction="never"
```

for all the menu items, except the first two.

As mentioned in the Android [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html):

> `never` : Never place this item in the app bar. Instead, list the item in the app bar's overflow menu.

Currently you're using `ifRoom` keyword, which will show the menu item in the action bar if there's enough space available for it. So, you won't be able to force max two items using this. From [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html):

> `ifRoom` : Only place this item in the app bar if there is room for it. If there is not room for all the items marked "ifRoom", the items with the lowest orderInCategory values are displayed as actions, and the remaining items are displayed in the overflow menu.

**P.S. :** What you're calling **more section** is referred as [overflow menu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) in the above text and in Android.